# NSDocument: how do you save & restore a document's window position?

Tags: swift, cocoa, osx-yosemite, nsdocument

I have a `NSDocument`-based app, and I'd like my window positions to be saved and restored when re-opening documents. Apple's documentation on this is pretty sparse, but what I've been able to piece together is that at some point, something in the app needs to call `NSWindow.setFrameUsingName()` and `NSWindow.setFrameAutosaveName()`.

What I haven't quite figured out is what point this needs to happen at, and what things need to do this. For example, this doesn't work at all:

```
// In my NSDocument class    
override func windowControllerDidLoadNib(aController: NSWindowController) {
    super.windowControllerDidLoadNib(aController)

    // Add any code here that needs to be executed once the windowController has loaded the document's window.
    aController.window?.setFrameUsingName("MainWindow")
    aController.window?.setFrameAutosaveName("MainWindow")
}
```

I've read various different pieces of documentation or forum answers that point to `awakeFromNib()` to be another area to do this, but I can't get that to work either.

I'm also confused / worried that this is somehow being affected by Auto Layout or something I've done wrong in Interface Builder - for example, this is how my window is set up in IB:

[image]

I don't particularly want my window centered, but the other options seem to lock it in place in fixed horizontal or fixed vertical positions, which I also don't really want. A side effect of having my window be centered is that my document windows no longer cascade, which I neither want nor can seem to stop from happening (note that `windowController.shouldCascadeWindows = true` isn't helping either).

So - what's going on here? I'm finding knowledge on this topic to be particularly unclear or misleading, and likely out of date for Cocoa development 2015, so a modern refresher on this would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1: In IB, give the window an autosave name.

[image]

Step 2: There is no step 2.

Comment: I find this has 2 problems: it makes every NSDocument window use the same origin and it doesn't restore the size of the window, just the origin. I am storing the frame in my document data but it always opens the document window in the default place and then moves it which really looks bad. There must be a standard solution for this.

Comment: Same problem as @SarahR

Answer (score 0):

The easiest place to set the name of the autosave name for the window frame is probably in your implementation of NSDocument.

If you override `makeWindowControllers()` as part of the implementation, you are creating the window controller(s) manually, and thus can set the name there:

```
override func makeWindowControllers() {
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name("MyDocumentStoryboard"), bundle: nil)
    let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier("MyDocument Window Controller")) as! MyDocumentWindowController

    // this assumes you have a stored property or a computed property `someUniqueIdentifier` that is as unique as possible for your document
    // and that you store on disk together with the rest of the document properties
    windowController.windowFrameAutosaveName = NSWindow.FrameAutosaveName(rawValue: someUniqueIdentifier)

    self.addWindowController(windowController)
}
```

If you instantiate your document window by overriding `windowNibName`, you should instead override the method `windowControllerDidLoadNib(_:)`, to set the autosave name on the window. I have not tested this code, but I assume it will work:

```
func windowControllerDidLoadNib(_ windowController: NSWindowController) {
    // this assumes you have a stored property or a computed property `someUniqueIdentifier` that is as unique as possible for your document
    // and that you store on disk together with the rest of the document properties
    windowController.windowFrameAutosaveName = NSWindow.FrameAutosaveName(rawValue: someUniqueIdentifier)
}
```